# Hangfire recurring job starting one hour early

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have a recurring job that is set on cron 0 9 * * * , but the job is firing one hour early, at 08:00 AM.

What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("SomethingSomething", 
            () => new SomethingSomethingSchedule().Execute(null), 
            Cron.Daily(9), 
            TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time"));
```

I'm using Hangfire version 1.7.0.0 with .Net Framework 4.7

Comment: Have you tried to use TimeZoneInfo.Local to see if that makes any difference? Also, what OS is hangfire running on vs where u access dashboard?

Comment: It is running in a windows machine on AWS server. Ther server is configured with ours timezone. It look like is using daylight saving time, but our country isn't participating  and the timezone "E. South America Standard Time" shouldn't change the clock.